# general scheme of 3d geometry storage and usage in OpenGL or DirectX

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, 3d, geometry, gpu

I know OpenGL only slight and all this docs and tutorials are damn hard to read so i do not helps.. I got some vision though how it could work and only would like some clarification or validation of my vision

I assume 3D world is build from 3d meshes, each mesh may be hold in some array or few arrays (storing the geometry for that mesh).. I assume also that some meshes may be sorta like cloned and used more than once on the scene.. So in my wision i got say 50 meshes but some of them are used more than once... Lets say those clones i would name as a instance of a mesh (each mesh may have 0 instances, 1 instance or more instances)

Is this vision okay? Some more may be added?

I understand that each instance should have its own position and orientation, so do we have some array of instances each element containing one pos-oriantation matrix? or thiose matrices only existing in the code branches (you know what i mean, i set such matrix then send a mesh then modify this position matrix then send the mesh again till all instances are sent) ?

Do this exhaust the geomety (non-shader) part of the things?
(then shaders part come which i also not quite understand, there is a tremendous amount of hoax on shaders where this geometry part seem more important to me, well whatever)

Can someone validate the vision i spread here?

Comment: In core opengl, most of the "geometry" stuff is setting up what the shaders get as inputs. The shaders themselves then take the inputs and output vertices and fragments, usually (but not necessarily) by taking in coordinate inputs and multiplying them by transformation matrices.

Comment: "tutorials are damn hard to read" No, they're really not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a model which will contain one or more meshes, a mesh that will contain one or more groups, and a group that will contain vertex data.

There is only a small difference between a model and a mesh such as a model will contain other data such as texture which will be used by a mesh (or meshes).

A mesh will also contain data on how to draw the groups such as a matrix.

A group is a part of the mesh which is generally used to move a part of the model using sub matrices. Take a look at "skeletal animation".

So as traditional fixed pipelines suggest you will usually have a stack of matrices which can be pushed and popped to define somewhat "sub-positions". Imaging having a model representing a dragon. The model would most likely consist of a single mesh, a texture and maybe some other data on the drawing. In the runtime this model would have some matrix defining the model basic position and rotation, even scale. Then when the dragon needs to fly you would move its wings. Since the wings may be identical there may be only 1 group but the mesh would contain data to draw it twice with a different matrix. So the model has the matrix which is then multiplied with the wing group matrix to draw the wing itself:

- push model matrix
- multiply with the dragon matrix
- push model matrix
- multiply with the wing matrix
- draw wing
- pop matrix
- push matrix
- multiply with the second wing matrix
- draw second wing
- pop matrix
- ... draw other parts of the dragon
- pop matrix

You can probably imagine the wing is then divided into multiple parts each again containing an internal relative matrix achieving a deeper level of matrix usage and drawing.

The same procedures would then be used on other parts of the model/mesh.

So the idea is to put as least data as possible on the GPU and reuse them. So when model is loaded all the textures and vertex data should be sent to the GPU and be prepared to use. The CPU must be aware of those buffers and how are they used. A whole model may have a single vertex buffer where each of the draw calls will reuse a different part of the buffer but rather just imagine there is a buffer for every major part of the mode such as a wing, a head, body, leg...

In the end we usually come up with something like a shared object containing all the data needed to draw a dragon which would be textures and vertex buffers. Then we have another dragon object which will point out to that model and contain all the necessary data to draw a specific dragon on the scene. That would include the matrix data for the position in the scene, the matrix for the groups to animate the wings and other parts, maybe some size or even some basic color to combine with the original model... Also some states are usually stored here such as speed, some AI parameters or maybe even hit points.

So in the end what we want to do is something like `foreach(dragon in dragons) dragon.draw()` which will use its internal data to setup the basic model matrices and use any additional data needed. Then the `draw` method will call out to all the groups, meshes in the model to be drawn as well until the "recursion" is done and the whole model is drawn.

So yes, the structure of the data is quite complicated in the end but if you start with the smaller parts and continue outwards it all fits together quite epic.

There are other runtime systems that need to be handled as well to have a smooth loading. For instance if you are in a game and there are dragons in vicinity you will not have the model for the dragon loaded. When the dragon enters the vicinity the model should be loaded in the background if possible but drawn only when needed (in visual range). Then when the dragon is gone you may not simply unload the model, you must be sure all of the dragons are gone and maybe even wait a little bit if someone might return. This then leads to something much like a garbage collector.

I hope this will help you to a better understanding.

Comment: this was helpful though i maybe expected a bit more of 'validation' or verification  of my wistion - it seems thai it like fits but still im not seeing it to much clear... one thing i am not sure is those position-oriantation matrices.. you said that probably whole geometry of the game may be hold in one vertex buffer - it this geometry has 150 movable parts where some are cloned yet on the scene (making say 500 movable parts on the scene) where are those 500 matroces stored?

Comment: In each of the model and or group. As I said a single data chunk may be used to draw each of the dragon wing by simply applying a different, mirrored matrix on that chunk.